# How can I align my labels, input, and textarea on same line?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

How can I align my labels, inputs, and textarea on the same line?

```
export default function Display() {
  ...
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleChange}>
      <div className="mb-4 align-middle">
        <label>
          Title :
          <input
            type="text"
            value={title}
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Title"
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          {" "}
          Comment :
          <textarea
            value={comment}
            placeholder="comment"
            onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
            cols="50"
            rows="3"
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here a picture (what I have vs expectations): [image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the parent div to `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row`

````
  ...
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleChange}>
      <div className="mb-4 align-middle" style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <label>
          Title :
          <input
            type="text"
            value={title}
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Title"
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          {" "}
          Comment :
          <textarea
            value={comment}
            placeholder="comment"
            onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
            cols="50"
            rows="3"
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Hi, it's not the result that I want please check my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/plants-forked-5evins?file=/src/CategoryDisplay.jsx) to see what I have with your code

Comment: You placed the `</div>` closing tag in the wrong place. Here's a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/plants-forked-w2on66

Comment: I don't see the modif in your sandboxCode

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` properties of tailwind css to align them in a same row. Also I have wrapped the the two inputs in two separate rate divs.

```
export default function Display() {
  ...
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleChange}>
      <div className="mb-4 align-middle flex flex-row items-center justify-center space-x-10">
        <div>
        <label>
          Title :
          <input
            type="text"
            value={title}
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Title"
          />
        </label>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label>
          {" "}
          Comment :
          <textarea
            value={comment}
            placeholder="comment"
            onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
            cols="50"
            rows="3"
          />
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```